# circle with expanding radius

Tags: plot, geometry, draw

I am trying to draw a circle segment from 0 to 360 degrees, with a radius that gets bigger while the circle is being drawn.
For example: at 0 degrees, the radius of the (to be drawn) circle is 10 and at 360 degrees, the radius is 12 (and all the values in between need to be calculated.
I this possible?

I am working in Tinkercad to try make this spiral, but I really have no clue to do this. google doesn't help me much further as all I can find is code snippets that actually use a "circle" drawing command. I, however, would think I need to go point by point?

Comment: You only need a sequence of arc-drawing, each one starting at the previous end, and with increasing radius. Some code you may post here help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If radius increment per round is constant - you need [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) (note there is a lot of spiral kinds with other radius/theta dependencies)

[image]

Radius linearly depends on angle (cumulative angle from beginning)

```
r = r0 + b * theta
```

For your example

```
 r0 = 10
 b = 1/Pi
```

In coordinates

```
x = cx + r * cos(theta)
y = cy + r * sin(theta)
```

[A method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742854/844416) for placing points at spiral equidistantly (or draw small ine segments)